# Empty string issue in python

Tags: python, string

I work on LeetCode problem "20. Valid Parentheses"

The task:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        
        values = {"()" : "", "{}" : "", "[]" : ""}
        
        
        def iteration(j):
            for key, value in values.items():
                k = j
                j = j.replace(key, f'{value}')
                
                if j != k:
                    return iteration(j)
                    
            if j == "":
                return True
            else:
                return False
            
        iteration(s)
```

The input is `s = "{[]}"`

So, when I reach the point when `j =""` it always fails at row `if j == "":` and return false and I have no idea why.

Comment: Your `isValid` function is not returning anything.
The current code does return True for the string in question once you add a return statement to `isValid`.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question is an image, not text. Also, this is a homework question. If you have an issue ask for specific help, not for an entire solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your code return a "none" you need a return in the function isValid:

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        
        values = {"()" : "", "{}" : "", "[]" : ""}
        
        
        def iteration(j):
            for key, value in values.items():
                k = j
                j = j.replace(key, f'{value}')
                
                if j != k:
                    return iteration(j)
                    
            if j == "":
                return True
            else:
                return False
            
        return iteration(s) #This is my change add a return
```